# as3 cache as bitmap listener?

Tags: actionscript-3

If I run `cacheAsBitmap = true` on a complex `Sprite` the caching can sometimes take up to a second.

Is there any way to check for when a `DisplayObject` has finished being *cached*?

Comment: That must be one heck of a complex Sprite!  With a Sprite that is large, complex, and changing often enough that 1 second is a big deal, are you sure you want to be caching it in the first place?

Comment: @meddlingwithfire I'm working on an AIR project for an Android device. There's a lot of text in the Sprite and cachine let's you scroll on the device a lot faster than leaving the text in glyphs. Because the text is dynamic (from XML), I am forced to do something of this nature :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no possible way. However, cacheAsBitmap is using a system of creating a Bitmap object under the hood. This bitmap gets drawn with the pixel information of the DisplayObject. Hence, if you desire a fine-grain control over how cacheAsBitmap works, I would say that you should instead use Bitmap/BitmapData directly, instead of using a Sprite/MovieClip with the cacheAsBitmap feature. Hope this helps!

This article should help you if you do not know how to work with Bitmaps:
http://www.flashgameblog.at/blog-post/2010/04/08/blitting-the-art-of-fast-pixel-drawing/